# why can't I load the AssemblyVersion attribute using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, reflection, .net-assembly

The assemblyinfo.cs file has the AssemblyVersion attribute, but when I run the following:

```
Attribute[] y = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes();
```

I get:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute

System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute

System.Reflection.AssemblyTrademarkAttribute
System.Reflection.AssemblyCopyrightAttribute
System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute
System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute
System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute
System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute
System.Reflection.AssemblyDescriptionAttribute
```

and yet I have checked countless times that this attribute is present in my code:

```
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.5.5.5")]
```

...and if I try to access it directly I get an exception:

```
Attribute x = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute)); //exception
```

I guess I won't be able to use that attribute, but how come .NET isn't reading it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `Assembly` already has a `Version` property.

Comment: are you sure? I see neither a static nor instance property with that name

Comment: You will have to use `GetName()` example `var y = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;`

Comment: [AssemblyVersion] is a really big deal in .NET.  The compiler treats the attribute specially, it uses it when it generates the metadata of the assembly.  And doesn't actually emit the attribute, that would be doing it twice.  Use the AssemblyName.Version instead, as shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will repeat Hans Passant's comment:

[AssemblyVersion] is a really big deal in .NET. The compiler treats the attribute specially, it uses it when it generates the metadata of the assembly. And doesn't actually emit the attribute, that would be doing it twice. Use the AssemblyName.Version instead, as shown.

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to just get the assembly version, it's pretty straight forward:

```
Console.WriteLine("The version of the currently executing assembly is: {0}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
```

The property is a type of [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx), which has `Major`, `Minor`, `Build`, and `Revision` properties.

Eg. an assembly of version `1.2.3.4` has:

- `Major` = `1`
- `Minor` = `2`
- `Build` = `3`
- `Revision` = `4`

Comment: It's weird that we can't get AssemblyVersionAttribute using reflection...

Answer (score 0):

(just to round out the flavors of getting a version...)

If you're trying to get **file** version info on an arbitrary assembly (i.e., not one loaded/running), you can use `FileVersionInfo` - however, note that this may not be the same `AssemblyVersion` specified in the metadata:

```
var filePath = @"c:\path-to-assembly-file";
FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath);

// the following two statements are roughly equivalent
Console.WriteLine(info.FileVersion);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", 
         info.FileMajorPart, 
         info.FileMinorPart, 
         info.FileBuildPart, 
         info.FilePrivatePart));
```

Comment: That's [AssemblyFileVersion].

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, good point; there *is* a potential distinction between file version and the "assembly" version gotten via reflection...although one could argue they *should* be the same... :)

Comment: @JerKimball i'd disagree about them needing to be the same. Fileversion causes no binding differences for an assembly, if you have a signed assembly and need to keep things working the same, you can increment your Fileversion and still allow older projects to work with "fixed" assembly (with the same assembly version)

Comment: @PaulFarry Actually, that's a **very** good point. You've sold me; I rescind my stance...well, whatever the opposite of what I implied was.